# FFMPEG c++ memory leak issue when reading the packet

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, memory-leaks, libav

I have written a program to read the frames from a video file. Everything works perfect except below described issue.
after reading the frame, when I call avcode_send_packet function, it leaks the memory.
I used av_packet_unref before reading the next frame. But still the memory leak is not resolved.
I am using FFMPEG latest 4.3 version on WIndows 10.

also av_frame_unref does not fix the memory leak. I think data buffer inside the packet does not get freed somehow I feel it is related to FFMPEG version issue as I see the similar coding done by other programmers on the internet.

Does any one have idea about how to fix this memory leak ?

----------------- code is as below-----------------------
... here code related to setting avformatcontext, and avcodeccontext.

```
while(1)
    {
        if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0)
        {
            if (packet->stream_index == videoindex)
            {

                ret = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, packet);//on executing this line, memory shoots up in MBs , everytime.
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    av_packet_unref(packet);
                    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to Decode packet. \n:%s", av_err2str(ret));
                    return -1;
                }

                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, pAvFrame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                {
                    av_packet_unref(packet);
                    continue;
                }
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    av_packet_unref(packet);
                    printf("Failed to Decode packet. \n");
                    return -1;
                }
                av_packet_unref(packet);

                
                {
                    //.. do something with the frame.
                }
                av_frame_unref(pAvFrame);

            }
            
            av_packet_unref(packet);
        }
}
```

Comment: Needs debugging details: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @santosh Can't reproduce this on Linux with neither 4.3 nor 4.3.1. Can you try to make a minimal program to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes, Yesterday, I commented my do something section code and  I observed deep that, memory increases in 4-8 mbs for each frame, But it happened for initial frames and later memory became stable around 50MB. 
Further, i found some issue in my dosomething section, in which i am converting frames to cv::mat and storing it for processing. Which I have to release after processing. That is the main cause I found and I will fix it using mat.data.release function at appropriate place.
Thanks.